# Where does the sound come from this board?

Tags: sound

As the question says, i can't figure out where the sound comes from on this board that i bought, nothing on the manuals and can't see any speaker on the board... It is a "RFID Proximity Entry Door Secure Lock Access Control System"

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What component is under the "Remove Seal After Washing" seal? Is it a buzzer?

Comment: @VE7JRO Updated the post :)

Comment: all you have to do is to put your finger on the component when it is making a sound and you will quickly discover if you are touching the correct component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a PCB mountable piezo buzzer. it makes sound in your "RFID Proximity Entry Door Secure Lock Access Control System"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a piezo buzzer, the component that had the sticker on it. It's likely louder now, with the sticker removed.